# SQL Query to set date activated for single row

Tags: sql, date, datetime, row

I have a registration form for users to submit and then when they click the activation link in their email, it activates their account `(AccountActivated = true`). This works fine, however, I also have a column called DateActivated set to smallinttime as the data type. I'm trying to find an SQL query that records the date that the account was activated.

This is the query I use to activate the account, so I'm guessing I need something similar to this:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET AccountActivated=1 WHERE 
   UserId=@UserId AND UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress"
```

So maybe something like this?

```
Dim sqlQuery2 As String = "UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET DateActivated=?? WHERE  
   UserId=@UserId AND UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress"
```

If someone could weigh in on this and let me know what the command is to set current date to the field, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Suggest you add a tag for the DB management program you are using.  (They all provide a function for this, example, `Date()` for MS Access.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all in the same query:

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET AccountActivated=1,DateActivated=GetDate() WHERE UserId=@UserId AND UMaryEmail=@txtEmailAddress"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! :D I'll check it as answered as soon as it lets me.